# How to use angular "element" parent or find methods to get access to the parent form?

Tags: angularjs

In a angular js directive which is on the "form input leve" I want a reference to the parent form in order to access the "on submit" event.

Right now, I can query the form by Id and add the submit.

But, I want to achieve it with angula's "element" method.
But it just won't work.

```
angular.module('app.common').directive('validateField', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '^form',
        scope: {
            error: '=validateField'
        },
        link: function(scope, el, attrs, form) {

            if (document.getElementById('testing')){

                var e = angular.element(document.getElementById('testing'))
                e.on('submit', function() {
                    console.log('Works!');
                })
            };

            el.parent('form').on('submit', function() {
                console.log('How do i do this?');
            })
        }
    };
}]);
```

Any ideas how?

**UPDATE**

I have found a solution, not sure it's an elegant one though:

```
// Validate field on "form submit".
            angular.element(el[0].form).on('submit', function() {
                validate();
            });
```

Comment: Where are you getting the variable `element` from? Is this a typo for `el` or `e`?

Comment: Yes, a typo :), I have found a solution, not sure it's elegant though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS selectors inside angular.element function,

```
angular.element('#myId'),
angular.element('.myClass')
```

With that said, you can abstract your directive even further when you are requiring the form controller, by using the $name property of it:

```
require: '^form',
link: function(scope,el,attrs,form) {
    ...
    if(form.$name) {
        var domForm = angular.element("[name=" + form.$name + "]")
        domForm.addClass('whee');
    }
}
```

Comment: I don;t want to use ID's frankie... plus, I'll have to check, you method might require jquery

Comment: Check the edit. It doesn't require jQuery, it uses angularjs internal jqLite.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, this looks 'wrong' to me.  Your directive shouldn't need to know about some specific element outside of its own scope in this way.  You would normally use some kind of service to synchronise data across components or provide the events/event handling that you need, or have your controller bring the two together.

Without seeing what you're trying to do in the event handler it's hard to know what you're trying to achieve, but it looks like you're just intending to do some validation.  Can you not do this using some custom AngularJS validation?

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation